# Dimensional of Vector Spaces Linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

Assume that V is finite-dimensional and S, T ∈ L (V). Show that
dim ker(ST) ≤ dim ker(S) + dim ker(T).

I am confused to what L(V) is defined as here because L should be linear transformations from V to some other space W.

But I think L(V) should be defined HERE AS linear transformations from/to V to/from some other space W such that S ∈ L(V, W), T ∈ L(U, V ). Am I correct in assuming this or should S ∈ L(V, W), T ∈ L(V, U )? (but then the composition makes no sense?)

Comment: Perhaps transformations from $V$ to $V$ (i.e. to itself)?

Comment: ah gotcha, so if i prove the statement for S ∈ L(V, W), T ∈ L(U, V ), that should include the case from V to V, right? since W, U can be V itself

Comment: Yes; if you prove the more general statement, the specific case follows.